# Invalid viewstate information may be corrupted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

I keep getting the following error message when I run my vb.net web app:

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

[View full message here.](http://www.box.net/signup/collablink/d_78538258/3243ef5f1f9ba)

After a good search, I came across [this Microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323744), which describes the problem exactly. The likely cause seems to be "scenario 2":

> Scenario 2: You modify your pages, which causes the shadow, copied files in the
>   Temporary ASP.NET files folder to be regenerated. A user has a copy of
>   the page that was requested before this change, and the user posts the
>   page after the files in that folder were regenerated.

But strangely- despite saying there is a hotfix, does not actually give the link to it.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

UPDATED: I appear to have prevented this error from happening by using `EnableEventValidation="False"` in the Page node of the markup [as recommended here](http://renditionprotocol.blogspot.com/2007/01/state-information-is-invalid-for-this.html). More of a work-around than a fix.

Comment: scenario 2 may not be only reason. Besides, in such case, you will get the said exception rarely (only when your web site file changes etc) - if you are consistently getting the said error then issue can be elsewhere. Another common cause of this issue can be changes in control tree - if you are dynamically creating controls etc then the said error can happen.

Comment: FYI - Turning off event validation is NOT a good solution.  It's there as part of a security mechanism to prevent a lot of bad things.

Comment: This is a hugely irritating issue and we've so far tracked it down on our systems to specific machines, NOT server-side code. Can recreate the issue by re-sorting a gridview in IE on Windows XP on certain machines. Other machines with seemingly similar setup do not have the issue. Other browsers never report the issue even on machines with the fault in IE.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to disable EnableEventValidation as explained in [Page.EnableEventValidation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx).

I got this issue before and came over it by deleting all files within ASP.NET Temporary Folder.

Folder Path:

.NET 2 : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
.NET 4: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 1):

IN one of my project, I was getting this error in Mozilla Firefox only that whenever i clicked a button or link.

It is because of the fact that firefox caches the form fields. Two ways to encounter this problem.

1. Write following snipet in your cs file

   protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnPreInit(e);
       if (Request.Browser.MSDomVersion.Major == 0) // If it is Non IE Browser
       {
           Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
       }
   }
2. In page load, write following statemet

   Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Now error has been removed and you can sleep with satisfaction.

http://yourtahir.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/the-state-information-is-invalid-for-this-page-and-might-be-corrupted/

Answer (score 0):

Might be overdate, but this cured my viewstate problems with ajax calls to page control.
Custom CompressedViewState :
add this code :

```
private ObjectStateFormatter _formatter = new ObjectStateFormatter();
protected override void
           SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _formatter.Serialize(ms, viewState);
        byte[] viewStateArray = ms.ToArray();
        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__COMPRESSEDVIEWSTATE",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
            CompressViewState.Compress(viewStateArray)));
    }
    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        string vsString = Request.Form["__COMPRESSEDVIEWSTATE"];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(vsString);
        bytes = CompressViewState.Decompress(bytes);
        return _formatter.Deserialize(
            Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }
```